# Loop Through rows selecting same columns one row down up to row 1000

Tags: vba

I have a range of cells in a row and the code I have does what it should but I need to loop through more rows up to 1000 performing the same procedure as in the first row of the code I pasted.  How can I loop through the other rows selecting the same columns and cells in each row?

I used the following and it worked but only for the one row I need to be able to loop through those cells in those columns up to row 1000, how can I do that?

```
Dim cel As Range

    'Find the 2nd most recent date:
BeforeDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("Q2,T2,W2,Z2,AC2,AF2"), 2)

For Each cel In Range("Q2,T2,W2,Z2,AC2,AF2")
    If cel.Value < BeforeDate Then
        cel.ClearContents
        cel.Offset(, -1) = ""
        cel.Offset(, -2) = ""
    End If
Next cel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:
(edit - added some error checking)

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim cel As Range, rng As Range, x As Long, BeforeDate, v

    For x = 2 To 1000

        'this works because Range is *relative to the Row*
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(x).Range("Q1,T1,W1,Z1,AC1,AF1")

        BeforeDate = Application.Large(rng, 2)

        If Not IsError(BeforeDate) Then
            For Each cel In rng.Cells
                v = cel.Value
                If Not IsError(v) Then
                    If v < BeforeDate Then
                        cel.Offset(, -2).Resize(1, 3).ClearContents
                    End If
                End If
            Next cel
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a run time error '13' Type mismatch on the, If cel.value < BeforeDate then, line

Comment: What are the values of cel.Value and BeforeDate when that happens?

Comment: BeforeDate says Error 2036 and cel.Value says 10/1/2017 which is the value in column Q and row 4

Comment: I added some error checking in the updated code above - try that out.  Can't see your data, so I can't say why you're getting an error from `Application.Large`

Comment: The new one with the error checking seem to work but it still leaves more than two dates if there are two instances with the same date but I can live with that.  Thanks